# Computing GCD. Why the output of 5 10 15 20 25 GCD is 1

Tags: java, greatest-common-divisor

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Chapter7_7_14 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] numsToFind = new int[5];
        System.out.println("Please enter 5 numbers now to find their GCD:");

        for (int i = 0; i < numsToFind.length; i++) {
            numsToFind[i] = input.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("The GCD of these 5 integers is " + gcd(numsToFind));
    }

    public static int gcd(int... numbers) {
        int minNum = numbers[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            if (numbers[i] < minNum) {
                minNum = numbers[i];
            }
        }

        int gcd = 1;
        boolean checkNum;

        for (int i = 2; i < minNum; i++) {
            checkNum = true;
            for (int j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++) {
                if (numbers[j] % i != 0)
                    checkNum = false;
            }
            if (checkNum) {
                gcd = i;
            }
        }
        return gcd;
    }
    
}
```

Why is my output wrong. When I input 5 numbers to find their gcd the answer is wrong. for example 5 10 15 20 25 gcd is 1 which is wrong right? can y'all please help me. I appreciate it so much

Comment: `for (int i = 2; i < minNum; i++) {` never reaches `minNum`, so `gcd` will never be 5

Comment: how can I fix it?

Comment: `for (int i = 2; i <= minNum; i++) {`